# How to correctly store secret keys on React App?

Tags: reactjs, security, private-key, secret-key, sensitive-data

I was happy lasts days using **.env **file with the npm dotenv package and saving there some secret keys i use on my React App...

On my first test opload I noticed that my webbApp runs ok **EVEN without specifying** the .env secret keys on the sever...

So then, was obious to feels like the **secret keys** are **anywhere** on the public files (**and yes**)

I was looking what im doing wrong, and found many documentation (official) that says literally:

> WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your React app!

> Environment variables are embedded into the build, anyone can view them by inspecting your app's files.

[official doc here if anyone is looking for more info](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

After 3 or 4 heartAttacks I write this to ask for help on this concept problem.

Anyone knows some documentation where i can read and understant HOW to correctly save sercret keys on this kind of apps (react apps) ?

why the hell is not like all time backend .env files ?

Some info I found, says something about to serve the secret key ontime from another server.

And... sounds stupid for me, i mean: Ok, i can do that but.. its just stupid cause then:

1. or server will serve the sercret keys "free" vía GET or something like this without no-login-needed.
2. or webbApp would need a secret_login_key to login and get the secret key <- in this case, where to store that secret_login_key ? its a infinite bucle ? XD

So:

1. it is posible.. (of course it is) so TRULY store secret keys on React App ? but where and how ?xD
2. what's the way you store the secret keys on ur react App and u are proud of it?

of course the login typing from keyboard user/pass its the "easyway" to have or not have access tho private information but.. what if i need this to be automatic from my webApp ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sensitive data should not be on the frontend, you can use env for information like API_URL but not for tokens and passwords

Here is the possible ways to get sensitive data in the frontend

- Http call to the **backend where secrets are hashed**
- Http call to an external secret management tool like [HashiCorp Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/)
- Use of **httpOnly** cookie that they couldn't be read from the frontend

If you are scripting user and password, you should try a tool like [jscrambler](https://blog.jscrambler.com/protecting-your-react-js-source-code-with-jscrambler) to secure your build js files

Comment: but after those actions it comes the "npm run build", so, the problem is the same: secret keys are gona be accesibles  on the public files.

Comment: i mean: my probem are not if the keys are or not are visibles on github, the problem is once the app is on produccion, deployed on my server.

Comment: I get you now, Check my update

Comment: Thanks again for your answer but still dislikes those options. To use any of those 3 options I sill need a user/pass to get the access, so, my frontendApp still have to store this user/pass anywhere on my frontend app

Comment: You need only one accessToken to access the backend and you can store it an httpOnly cookie, It is used to access the backend and you can't read it's value on your browser

Comment: xD. This is a infinity bucle for me. Because to build that httpOnly cookie i need to code a script that will type the user/pass  i want to sotre on that cookie. so, we are on the beggining of the problem again.

Comment: Check my update, you may need a tool like jsscrambler

Answer (score 0):

For automatic access to your webapp from the frontend (React), you need a bearer token that is stored in localstorage (bad idea) or as a cookie of the user's browser. Popular example of bearer token is JWT token.

This is how you generate a bearer token on the user's browser: by using Universal Login (login with Google/Fb/Github/Twitter etc) to a provider like Auth0.

React has to communicate with Auth0, Auth0 will authorise the user and return a bearer token that is stored in localstorage (bad idea)/cookie of the browser.

This is what you are trying to do:[Call a protected API from React](https://developer.auth0.com/resources/guides/spa/react/basic-authentication#call-a-protected-api-from-react)

This is the walk through example of how to do it: [Basic Authentication Quick React Setup](https://developer.auth0.com/resources/guides/spa/react/basic-authentication#quick-react-setup)

Here are some example use cases with different application architecture scenarios:[Application Architecture Scenarios](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/architecture-scenarios)

React's documentation is correct, secrets should not be used directly in the React project. But the problem is how to ensure only authorised users get access to protected paths. One way is to use username and password login but you said its the "easyway" and you need it to be automatic. So another way is to ensure authorisation by bearer token stored in localstorage(bad idea)/cookie of the user's browser - this creates a new problem: how to generate a bearer token to allow access. The solution is to use universal login by Auth0 (or Oauth, or OpenID, or Google Authenticator, or some other token generator that the user can possess (like a mobile app (Google Authenticator) or a hardware token)).

Comment: tyanks for help, but not helped XD. I mean:

I know how to use tokens, but this not solve my problem. For example: You can asume im using Laravel with auth controller (sancum middleware) all working good, perfect. But still my webApp would need a user/password to reach this token. <- where to store this user/password on the webbApp ? I mean: i don't wanna type from keyboard, i wanna automatic login from key/value but can't find where to store this key/value correctly safe

Comment: Try this:  -store your key/value as a .txt file somewhere on your machine (/Documents/keyvalue.txt)  -in your React project, use fs.open('/Documents/keyvalue.txt') and store it as a variable in your code

Answer (score 0):

When API calls are made from the frontend (i.e. your react app) anyone using your app can see the request that was made (with tokens, keys, etc.). You should always secret vars to an `.env` file and keep this file only on your local machine.The best way to handle this, in my opinion, is to use a framework like [next](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) or [remix](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/data-loading) that allow you to create functions/api routes that run on the server. This way your frontend makes a request (no sensitive info there) to your server that has access to your keys/tokens. The real call to an external API will be made from the server (so users won't have access to any sensitive data). Not sure if this is something you're interested in but I feel like it's the best way to deal with API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you have two seperate folders, one for front end and the other for backend, that just having one env file in the root folder will not suffice. I had to create a .env file as well for the front-end folder while following React's naming convention. However, one work around that I learned is that you can store your secret key in a file which you have .gitignore ignore.

Answer (score -3):

I suggest creating a ".env" to store all your secret keys.
In your ".env" file you can make this one
Eg:

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY=5155645fdsffsdfs
```

And in your component, you'll call it
Eg :

```js
const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
```

Comment: this is the start point of my question. -> when you "npm run build" a "create react app" it build all info even inclusive de .env so, the varaible inside de .env are included for everybody who wanna search them in the public files.